Undefined references while compiling apache server on raspberry PI
I am getting these results when I run make
/home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread         -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo       /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_sub_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_exchange_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nic/Downloads/httpd/srclib/apr/.libs/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:48: htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nic/Downloads/httpd/support'
make[1]: *** [/home/nic/Downloads/httpd/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nic/Downloads/httpd/support'
make: *** [/home/nic/Downloads/httpd/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1


I think there is a missing library and I just don't which one. Pleas help
